# Could not open '/lib/ld.so.1': No such file or directory when cross compiling mips

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, qemu, mips32

I am trying to compile some C code with the intention of executing it on a Mips Linux o32 embedded system. I have simple C code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

and compiled it with

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -mfp32 helloworld.c
```

I know I cant run it on my linux machine so to test it first I got qemu and tried to run it with

```
qemu-mips ./a.out
```

But I am getting an error

```
qemu-mips: Could not open '/lib/ld.so.1': No such file or directory
```

Which I suspect has to do with the fact that I am including stdio.h but did not link it. How could I fix this.

I expected the code to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **install the LibC** for this architecture, and **set the elf interpreter prefix**.

```
sudo apt install libc6-mips-cross
```

Depending of the target architecture, it might be another LibC such as

```
sudo apt install libc6-mipsel-cross
```

*Qemu* will look in `/etc/qemu-binfmt/` for the architecture corresponding elf interpreter prefix. Create a symlink to the correct folder.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/qemu-binfmt
sudo ln -s /usr/mips-linux-gnu/ /etc/qemu-binfmt/mips
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/mipsel-linux-gnu /etc/qemu-binfmt/mipsel
```

If you have a custom libc and linker, you can use them with the `LD_PRELOAD` trick.
For example if I have these files :

```
.
├── a.out
└── lib
    ├── ld.so.1
    └── libc.so.6
```

You can use the following command :

```
 qemu-mips -L . -E LD_PRELOAD=./lib/ld.so.1 -E LD_PRELOAD=./lib/libc.so.6 ./a.out
```

Comment: IMHO it's more convenient to point to a folder where all the files live, e.g. `qemu-mips -L /mnt/mips ./a.out`, where `/mnt/mips` is e.g. an image of the corresponding mips system

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an error
>
> qemu-mips: Could not open '/lib/ld.so.1': No such file or directory
>
> Which I suspect has to do with the fact that I am including stdio.h but did not link it.

This is because you have compiled a dynamically linked executable. You should be able to see it in the `readelf -l a.out | grep interpreter` output. So when you run it the QEMU needs the target dynamic linker, but it cannot find one, because the `/lib` contains your host binaries and there's no `ld.so.1` in it.

It can be fixed by building static executable (`mips-linux-gnu-gcc -mfp32 -static helloworld.c`), or by supplying the location of the target MIPS rootfs (containing `lib/ld.so.1` and other needed libraries) in the QEMU command line (`qemu-mips -L<path to directory with MIPS rootfs> ./a.out`).

Comment: Compiling static seems the way to go since I am going to import it onto my embedded device. This worked thank you so much!